# Golang MongoDB Increment Integer Value

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm using this official library

`https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver`

and here is one of my documents in MongoDB

```
{
    "_id": "5f0ebe6dfcee0f34c64b23b0",
    "userID": "user A",
    "unread": 1,
    "projectID": 2
}
```

the problem is I want to increment (and maybe decrement too) the field "unread"

I have tried using "$inc" and it become like this

```
{
    "_id": "5f0ebe6dfcee0f34c64b23b0",
    "userID": "user A",
    "unread": {
        "$incr": 1,
    },
    "projectID": 2
}
```

and I think there's would be 2 conditions

1. document already exists
2. document doesn't yet exists

if I'm using `UpdateOne` or `UpdateMany` it will be a problem again if the document doesn't yet exists

someone that help me out from this will appreciated

thank you, cheers ^^

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve, and include the code you've tried. Using `UpdateOne` and `UpdateMany` are 2 different cases. You most likely don't want to insert a non-existing document when using `UpdateMany`.

Comment: Would be good to know what use case you are trying to achieve. That helps other people in referring this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have got the answer. So I did code like this

```
_, err = m.db.Collection("inbox_counter").UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{
    "userID":    v.UserID,
    "projectID": v.ProjectID,
}, bson.D{
    {"$inc", bson.D{{"unread", 1}}},
}, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return err
}
```

I am using UpdateOne because there's only one document for each user and project id

And you can use operator `$inc` to increment the value

thanks to @Gibbs for refer me to use `upsert`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `upsert` - It will update if it is present else inserts.

[Refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists-upsert)

```
db.collectionName.update(
   { item: "ZZZ135" },   // Find query 
   {
     "$set":{                     // Update document
      item: "ZZZ135",
      stock: 5,
      tags: [ "database" ]
     }
   },
   { upsert: true }      // Option
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.getCollection('table_name').update(
   { "key": "value" },   // Find query 
   {
     "$set":{                     // Update document
         "key": value
     },
    "$setOnInsert":{                     // Addd on Insert only
         "key1": value
     },
     "$inc": {
         "numberKey": 1 // Increment unread Or To decrement use -1
      }
   },
   { upsert: true } 
);
```